# How to avoid Multiple User Input at same time?

Tags: performance, android, android-progressbar

How to make my application to avoid multiple user inputs at same time.

For Example if a button is clicked i should make all other components should be disabled until i am getting response for the previous click.

I had tried about progressbar with asynchronous task, other than this is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can display progress dialog, I would recommend to use AsyncTask and display progress dialog for the execution time

Comment: what do you mean by disable all until I'm getting response? Why don't you hide them for time being on `onPreExecute()` and show them on `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: Thanks Syed Waqas.., Yeah i had done with progress bar searching for some other answers.

Comment: Hi @Aniruddha , Making the other component to freeze state until the previous request is processed

Comment: If it's a short operation that runs on the UI thread, it blocks the UI thread and you do not need any additional measures. If it's a long operation, you probably need a _cancel_ button.